# Referencing a yet to be created element in another element's event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an element created dynamically, for which I have already attached an event listener to, like below:

```
radio.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   document.getElementById(action[1]).style.display = 'block';
});
```

The 'action[1]' is a string which will be the id of an element yet to be created.  I have tried this, and it seems to work.  I know the event listener's function will only be fired on the 'click' event, and by then the 'action[1]' element will exist.  But it seems like I'm attaching an invalid function when the addEventListener is attached to my 'radio' element.  Will this cause problems?

Comment: The body of a function isn't evaluated until the function is called. There's no problem with access variables that are assigned between adding the event listener and triggering the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I want to close this with an answer, but the answer, comes from Barmar, so I don't take credit for it.  As stated in the comment,

> The body of a function isn't evaluated until the function is called.
> There's no problem with access variables that are assigned between
> adding the event listener and triggering the event.

Question is answered.